# accessing oam server hosted in https from java client program

Tags: authentication, https, oracle11g, java-client

Hi i have a requirement to access a oam server which is hosted in https protocol.I got the certificate and the obaccess.xml files from the server to access.But still am facing some issues.Below is my code

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import oracle.security.am.asdk.*;

public class JAccessClient
{
  public static final String ms_resource ="//1.1.1.1:14101/rest/userprofile";               
  public static final String ms_protocol = "https";
  public static final String ms_method = "GET";
  public static final String ms_login = "admin";
  public static final String ms_passwd = "admin";
  public static final String m_configLocation = "D:\\Configfiles";

  public static void main(String argv[])
  {
      AccessClient ac = null;
      try
      {
            System.out.println("Entered Try..");
            ac = AccessClient.createDefaultInstance(m_configLocation,AccessClient.CompatibilityMode.OAM_10G);
            System.out.println("Created Default Instance..");
            ResourceRequest rrq = new ResourceRequest(ms_protocol, ms_resource,ms_method);
            System.out.println("Created Resource Request object..");

            if (rrq.isProtected())
            {
                System.out.println("Resource is protected.");
                AuthenticationScheme authnScheme = new AuthenticationScheme(rrq);
                if (authnScheme.isForm())
                {
                    System.out.println("Form Authentication Scheme.");
                    Hashtable creds = new Hashtable();
                    creds.put("userid", ms_login);
                    creds.put("password", ms_passwd);
                    UserSession session = new UserSession(rrq, creds);
                    if (session.getStatus() == UserSession.LOGGEDIN)
                    {
                        if (session.isAuthorized(rrq))
                        {
                            System.out.println("User is logged in and authorized for the"+"request at level " + session.getLevel());
                            System.out.println("User Identity:"+session.getUserIdentity());
                            System.out.println("Status: "+session.getStatus());
                            System.out.println("Start time:"+session.getStartTime());
                            System.out.println("Session Token:"+session.getSessionToken());
                            System.out.println("Last Usetime:"+session.getLastUseTime());

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("User is logged in but NOT authorized");
                        }
                        //user can be loggedout by calling logoff method on the session object
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("User is NOT logged in");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("non-Form Authentication Scheme.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Resource is NOT protected.");
            }
  }
  catch (AccessException ae)
  {
     //System.out.println("Access Exception: " + ae.getCause());
          ae.getStackTrace();
  }
  ac.shutdown();
```

}
}
I have placed the obaccess.xml and the cwallet.sso in the path D://ConfigFiles.When i run the above code i get the error as below

```
Entered Try..
Jul 05, 2013 9:04:49 AM oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.Configuration setEncryptedPassword
SEVERE: Failed to perform encrypt password operation.
Jul 05, 2013 9:04:49 AM oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.Configuration setEncryptedPassword
SEVERE: 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9a"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at oracle.security.am.common.nap.util.ObCrypt.convert(ObCrypt.java:163)
at oracle.security.am.common.nap.util.ObCrypt.decrypt(ObCrypt.java:100)
at oracle.security.am.common.nap.util.ObCrypt.decrypt(ObCrypt.java:214)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.Configuration.decrypt(Configuration.java:810)
at     oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.Configuration.decryptPassword(Configuration.java:766)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.Configuration.setEncryptedPassword(Configuration.java:242)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.ConfigXMLHandler.processConfig(ConfigXMLHandler.java:570)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.ConfigXMLHandler.readConfigurationFromFile(ConfigXMLHandler.java:124)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.AccessClient.initialize(AccessClient.java:608)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.AccessClient.<init>(AccessClient.java:527)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.AccessClient.createDefaultInstance(AccessClient.java:234)
at JAccessClient.main(JAccessClient.java:21)

Jul 05, 2013 9:04:49 AM oracle.security.am.asdk.AccessClient initialize
SEVERE: Oracle Access SDK initialization failed. 
oracle.security.am.asdk.AccessException: OAMAGENT-02072: Failed to perform encrypt  password operation.
at oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.Configuration.setEncryptedPassword(Configuration.java:263)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.ConfigXMLHandler.processConfig(ConfigXMLHandler.java:570)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.ConfigXMLHandler.readConfigurationFromFile(ConfigXMLHandler.java:124)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.AccessClient.initialize(AccessClient.java:608)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.AccessClient.<init>(AccessClient.java:527)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.AccessClient.createDefaultInstance(AccessClient.java:234)
at JAccessClient.main(JAccessClient.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9a"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at oracle.security.am.common.nap.util.ObCrypt.convert(ObCrypt.java:163)
at oracle.security.am.common.nap.util.ObCrypt.decrypt(ObCrypt.java:100)
at oracle.security.am.common.nap.util.ObCrypt.decrypt(ObCrypt.java:214)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.Configuration.decrypt(Configuration.java:810)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.Configuration.decryptPassword(Configuration.java:766)
at oracle.security.am.asdk.impl.Configuration.setEncryptedPassword(Configuration.java:242)
... 6 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at JAccessClient.main(JAccessClient.java:75)
```

I am new to OAM and here is where i am stuck.Any help regarding this will be really helpful.

Comment: Hi,
Where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have not created an instance of an AMClient. The OAM SDK requires that you create an instance of an AMCLient before you do anything else with the SDK such as starting a new session.

Comment: Hi Bill,
Can you please elaborate on your answer? I have run into same issue.
Can you point to any document?